# Numerical Integration using Gauss Quadrature

Tags: numerical-methods, gaussian-integral

I have the following problem:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhFmI.png

It want us to integrate it using 4-point gauss quadrature
and the Relevant error should become 0% compared to its Exact value of integration
using Excel or spreadsheet

Our prof teach us only how to do it on Single Integral

Somebody here know how to do it on Double Integral?

I also want it on manual solving to understand

Comment: Hint: choose a basis on which the integral is exact, like in the one-dimensional case.

Comment: I already tried that one:
I solve it using the dx first then do it on dy(adding the n=4 to each y values) but ending up on a negative relevant errors

Comment: I tried also to google it but then I dont find any appropriate formulas for my problem

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^2\int_0^3f(x, y)dxdy &= 
\left|
\begin{aligned}
x &= u + 1\text{ }(u \in [-1, 1]) \\
y &= \frac{3}{2}v + \frac{3}{2} \\
dxdy &= \frac{3}{2}dudv
\end{aligned}
\right| = \\
&= \int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\underbrace{f\left(u + 1, \frac{3}{2}v + \frac{3}{2}\right)}_{g(u, v)}dudv = \\
&= \int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1g(u, v)dudv = \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^4{\omega_j\left(\sum_{i=1}^4\omega_ig(t_i, t_j)\right)} = \boldsymbol{\omega}'\mathbf{G}\boldsymbol{\omega}, 
\end{aligned}
$$

where $t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4$ are nodes, and $\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3, \omega_4$ are weights.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{\omega}&=\pmatrix{\omega_1 \\ \omega_2 \\ \omega_3 \\ \omega_4} \\
\mathbf{G} &= \pmatrix{
g(t_1, t_1) & g(t_1, t_2) & g(t_1, t_3) & g(t_1, t_4) \\
g(t_2, t_1) & g(t_2, t_2) & g(t_2, t_3) & g(t_2, t_4) \\
g(t_3, t_1) & g(t_3, t_3) & g(t_2, t_3) & g(t_3, t_4) \\
g(t_4, t_1) & g(t_4, t_4) & g(t_2, t_3) & g(t_4, t_4) \\
} = \\
&= \pmatrix{
f\left(t_1+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_1+1)\right) & f\left(t_1+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_2+1)\right) & f\left(t_1+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_3+1)\right) & f\left(t_1+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_4+1)\right) \\
f\left(t_2+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_1+1)\right) & f\left(t_2+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_2+1)\right) & f\left(t_2+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_3+1)\right) & f\left(t_2+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_4+1)\right)  \\
f\left(t_3+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_1+1)\right) & f\left(t_3+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_2+1)\right) & 
f\left(t_3+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_3+1)\right) & f\left(t_3+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_4+1)\right)  \\
f\left(t_4+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_1+1)\right) & f\left(t_4+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_2+1)\right) & 
f\left(t_4+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_3+1)\right) & f\left(t_3+1, \frac{3}{2}(t_4+1)\right)  \\
}  
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The four points Gauss rule has degree 7... So, if you compute the iterated integrals using this rule, you must get the exact value of the double integral. Keep in mind that you must adapt the integration points and weights when integrating in intervals other than [-1,1].
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2 \int_0^3 f(x,y) dy dx =& \int_0^2 \left(\int_0^3 f(x,y) dy\right)dx\approx \int_0^2\sum_{i=1}^4 \omega_i f(x,y_i) dx \\
\approx &\sum_{j=1}^4 \tilde \omega_j \sum_{i=1}^4 \omega_i f(x_j, y_i)
= \sum_{i,j = 1}^4 \tilde \omega_{j} \omega_i f(x_j, y_i)
\end{align*}

---

$$
\int_a^b g(x)\, dx = \frac{b-a}{2}\int_{-1}^1 f\left(\frac{b-a}{2} t + \frac{a+b}{2} \right)\, dt
$$

So, if $u_i, \xi_i$ are the points and weights for the four point gauss rule in the interval [-1,1], you have that
$$
\int_a^b g(u) du \approx \sum_{i=1}^4 \frac{(b-a)\xi_i}{2} f\left(\frac{b-a}{2} \cdot u_i + \frac{a+b}{2}\right)
$$